# using a list as values to a format string without having to list each item separately

Tags: python

```
def createSVGStyleTransformationMatrix(self, transformMatrix):
    return "matrix(%f %f %f %f %f %f)"%(transformMatrix[0],transformMatrix[1],transformMatrix[2],transformMatrix[3],transformMatrix[4],transformMatrix[5])
```

As all the substitutions are from the same list and in sequence I was hoping there was a neater way to do this.  Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `len(transformMatrix) == 6`, then you can use

```
 return "matrix(%f %f %f %f %f %f)" % tuple(transformMatrix)
```

Comment: Change it to `tuple(transformMatrix)` for a +1. `%` doesn't like lists.

Comment: maybe `"matrix(%f %f %f %f %f %f)" % tuple(transformMatrix[:6])` is closer to the intended for the case that transformMatrix could be longer than 6.

Comment: @glglgl: that depends, maybe if `len(transformMatrix) > 6` the OP wants an exception to be raised.

Comment: While the given modification is closer to the code given in the question, an exception here might be indeed useful.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, use the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method (version 2.6+), which is preferred over string interpolation(`%`) in Python 3.x:

```
return "matrix(%f %f %f %f %f %f)".format(*transformMatrix)
```

*The `*` instructs the Python interpreter to [unpack](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the arguments from a list or tuple*.

Answer (score 4):

```
"matrix(%s)" % " ".join(["%f" % i for i in transformMatrix])
```

(not tested)

EDIT: tested :-)

Comment: maybe `"matrix(%s)" % " ".join(["%f" % i for i in transformMatrix[:5]])` is closer to the intended for the case that `transformMatrix` could be longer than 5.

Comment: of course. And maybe my code works also when the matrix changes… depends on the needs. But you are right :-)

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to add it to the other answer *blush, shame on me*

Comment: Why format it in the list comprehension?
`"matrix(%s)" % " ".join([str(i) for i in transformMatrix])`

Comment: Why use list comprehensions? Just get rid of `[]` and use generator expressions.

Comment: @utdemir — can you elaborate?

Comment: Just use: `"matrix(%s)" % " ".join("%f" % i for i in transformMatrix)`. Using `()` instead of `[]` creates a generator expression, and if a generator expression is the only argument to a function, you don't have to use double paranthesis.

Answer (score 3):

```
"matrix({})".format(" ".join(map(str, transformMatrix)))
```

or I think it's simplier:

```
"matrix(" + " ".join(map(str, transformMatrix) + ")"
```

String concatenation shouldn't be a problem with three small strings, but should avoid it using large number of or big strings.

Comment: Not working: e.g. `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found`